# Prove $f$ is a measurable function. Proof correction.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(\Omega_1, \mathcal F_1, \mathbb P_1)$ be a complete measurable space and there exists a set $A \subset \Omega_1$ that is not in $\mathcal F_1$. Let $(\Omega_2, \mathcal F_2, \mathbb P_2)$ a measurable space, where $\Omega_2 = \{1,2,3\}, \mathcal F_2 = \{\{1,2\}, \{3\},\emptyset, \{1,2,3\}\}$ and $\mathbb P_2$ is a Delta Dirac on $3$.

Consider the followig function:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in A \\
2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Then f is $\mathcal F_1/\mathcal F_2$ measurable.
We prove that $f^{-1}(C)\in\mathcal{F}_1$ for all $C\in\mathcal{F}_2$.

We have the following cases:

1. If $C=\emptyset$, then $f^{-1}(C) = \emptyset\in\mathcal{F}_1$.
2. If $C=\{3\}$, then $f^{-1}(C) = \emptyset\in\mathcal{F}_1$.
3. If $C$ is $\{1,2\}$ or $\{1,2,3\}$ , then $f^{-1}(C) = \Omega_1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.